# In joomla i want to add multilanguage facility on administrator end in a custom component

Tags: joomla1.7

I have created custom components in joomla like,event.In these component how i will add multilanguage features that's why i add title and content in a multilanguage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it is important to understand that the Joomla multilingual features are not intended to be a full blown language manager. You will still need to use an additional language manager in order to truly display all of your content in multiple languages. Joomfish has been the most popular, but it does not have a version for 1.7/2.5 yet, though it is supposed to be released shortly. You might want to try FaLang, it's a Joomfish fork and 2.5 compatible. This should help -

Joomla Language Switcher tutorial - http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Switcher_Tutorial_for_Joomla_1.6

How to add Joomfish to your component - http://docs.joomla.org/Adding_Joomfish_functionality_to_custom_components (this is for 1.5 but the process should be similar for 1.7 and FaLang)

Joomfish - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/460

FaLang - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/languages/multi-lingual-content/18210